# JSP - Basic example of Apache FileUpload

Tags: java, apache, jsp, file-upload

I'm looking for a very basic example of the use of Apache FileUploader - one that actually has explanation of the components. All I can find on Google just seems to dive right into the code without any understanding imparted.

The libraries are installed and I've had a shot at it, but I just don't understand the code and I hate being a copy-coder.

The use is for a single file upload, from an HTML form. Multiple files are not needed (which most tutorials also focus on).

Any help or links would be useful, thanks.

Comment: Have you had a look at the original documenatation? It is very detailed.

Comment: @Sascha - Detailed, yes. Understandable for a novice, no. Their 'most basic example' doesn't explain anything.

Comment: @ Luiggi - Thanks for the link. Looks useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm has necessary comments and explanation for the file upload.

You can also see [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: You should flag the question as duplicated instead of using the link as part of your answer.

Comment: Done. Marked as duplicate.

Comment: You should further vote up answers you accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form name="form1" action="forward.jsp" method="post" >
      File Upload:<input type="file" name="upload" size="100"/>
                  <input type="submit" value="submit" size="100"/>

   </form>
```

**In forward.jsp**

`out.println(request.getparameter(upload));//returns filename only rather than whole path`

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't address the issue of Apache FileUpload.

Comment: i Don't get your question

Comment: Ravindra already gave me a useful link, and I've been able to make progress. Your answer makes no use of the UploadFile library, and so cannot use multipart encoding, and so cannot upload files to a server.